# unable to pass model from controller to view in httpget method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i want to do paging in question dta is i want to display 1 question per page.

This is my model:

```
 public class Question
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionName { get; set; }
        public List<QuestionOption> Options { get; set; }
        public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
    }

    public class QuestionOption
    {
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public string OptionName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult TestStarted(int TestId)
        {
            int pg_cnt = 0;
            ViewBag.ct = 0;
            ViewBag.Test_id = TestId;

            List<Question> model = new List<Question>();
            model = new Test_Planning().Fetch_Question_By_Test(TestId);
            pg_cnt = model.Count();
            ViewBag.total = pg_cnt;
            if (Request.QueryString["cnt"] != null)
            {
                int count = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["cnt"].ToString());
                ViewBag.ct = count;
                return View(model.Skip(1 * count).Take(1));
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model.Skip(0).Take(1));
            }
        }
```

this is my view page:

```
@model List<EAssessmentNew.Models.Question>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestStarted";
    Layout = "~/Views/StudentMaster.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("TestStarted","Student",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div style="margin-left: 30px;">
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <div>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model[i].QuestionId)
                    <span>@Model[i].QuestionName</span>
                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Options.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        <div>  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>Model[i].SelectedOption,Model[i].Options[j].OptionId)
                            <span>@Model[i].Options[j].OptionName</span>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        }


        <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer"  />

        <input type="button" value="End Test" />

    </div>
}

@{
    int cnt = 0;
    int sel = 0;
    int t_id = 0;
  }


@{
    sel = ViewBag.ct;
    cnt = ViewBag.total;
    t_id = ViewBag.TestId;
  }
<span style="margin-left:350px">
   @Html.ActionLink("First", "TestStarted", new { cnt = 0,TestId=t_id }, new { style = "color:#000;display:inline-block;width:60px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #CCC;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;margin-left:5px;background-color:#F8F7FC;border-radius:10px;" })
@for (int i = 0; i < (cnt / 1); i++)
{
    if (sel == i)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink((i + 1).ToString(), "TestStarted", new { cnt = i,TestId=t_id }, new { style = "color:#000;display:inline-block;width:40px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #CCC;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;margin-left:5px;background-color:#CCC;border-radius:10px;" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink((i + 1).ToString(), "TestStarted", new { cnt = i,TestId=t_id }, new { style = "color:#000;display:inline-block;width:40px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #CCC;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;margin-left:5px;background-color:White;border-radius:10px;" })
    }
}
 @Html.ActionLink("Last", "TestStarted", new { cnt = (cnt / 1) - 1,TestId=t_id }, new { style = "color:#000;display:inline-block;width:60px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #CCC;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;margin-left:5px;background-color:#F9F9F9;border-radius:10px;" })

</span>
```

i am getting all question in my with its selected answer in this list:

**model = new Test_Planning().Fetch_Question_By_Test(TestId);**

but problem is on this line on view page:

**@model List**

when this line is executed on controller side:

**return View(model.Skip(0).Take(1));**

it throws the error.

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+d__3a`1[EAssessmentNew.Models.Question]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EAssessmentNew.Models.Question]'.**

skip method return type is ienumerable and i have taken taken list on my view page.

can any one provide me solution for this????????

i am badly struck on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message clearly explains that you are passing an `Enumerable` to the view but the view wants a `List`.

Try adding a `ToList()` into your `return` statements. For example:

```
return View(model.Skip(0).Take(1).ToList());
```